# Determine all functions $\Bbb R _{\ge 0} \rightarrow \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ such that $f(x)+f(y)+2xy=f(x+y) $

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Determine all functions $\Bbb R _{\ge 0} \rightarrow \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ such that $f(x)+f(y)+2xy=f(x+y) $

The only nice progress I could make was $f(x)=x^2$ is a solution and $f(0)=0 $

when we take $f(x)=x^2$ , we get $f(x)+f(y)+2xy=x^2+y^2+2xy =f(x+y) $

and for $(x,y)=(0,0)$, we get $2f(0)=f(0)$ $\implies f(0)=0$

I tried making substitution , but couldn't make a nice one , also I think Cauchy might help since we have the FE similar to  $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y) $

---

If possible, can someone post hints rather than solution, it helps me a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $g(x)=f(x)-x^{2}$ is an additive function.

Comment: See [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-f-x-if-f-x-y-f-x-f-y-2xy-1)

Comment: Without any additional assumptions we cannot say what $f$ is. If $f$ is continuous (or at least measurable) then additivity implies $g(t)=ct$ for  some constant $c$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $f$ and $g$ are two solutions, what can you say about $f-g$?

Comment: What can you say?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking me now what my hint meant a year ago. You can show that $f-g$ satisfies Cauchy's functional equation; therefore once one solution is found, you can find all others by adding a Cauchy solution.

Comment: Because I didn't understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** As you noted out that $f(x)=x^2$ satisfies the conditions, its natural to define the function $g(x):=f(x)-x^2$ or simply $f(x)=g(x)+x^2$.

> Is this an additive Cauchy in $g$?

> Can you show $g$ is bounded in a non-trivial interval?

> Can you use the fact that $f$ is bounded?

> Note that $g(x)> -10$ in the interval $[0,3]$ and so $g$ is linear but as $f(0)=0$ we get, $f(x)=kx+x^2$ for some $k$.

Comment: I just had a tiny doubt , well it was stated in 4.1 ( evan's handout ) that "f is bounded (either above or below) in any nontrivial interval." here does  any mean "any one non-trivial interval "  or "every nontrivial interval " ?

Comment: @Shubhangi It means in any one interval... For instance, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423494/687233 OR https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c985173h1969998_cauchy_equations :P

Comment: Oh.. I got it ..Thanks :) Actually Evan's language was a bit confusing in that handout :D  But yeah, now it's clear :) . Thank you so much , BTW is the MDP  group active rn ?

Comment: @Shubhangi Yeah yeah, its very active!! Not even a single message is posted there after the day your left :P

Comment: Aww... I see  :rotfl: . Anyways Thanks, again for helping me :)